# How to disable Android gamepad default controls?

Tags: android, gamepad

I'm trying to make an app which is controlled by a gamepad. I've gotten it to work alright, but Android has some default controls that it uses for navigation when a gamepad is plugged in, such as the B button takes you back a menu. I want to be able to use the buttons that Android has defaults for. Is there a way to disable the default Android controls? I can't find any thing about the default Android gamepad controls, let alone how to disable them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. For anyone who needs this in the future, here's how to do it. When you add in the onKeyDown override command, this is what it looks like.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

As I understand it, that return line gives the Android system access to the button presses. However if you make it always return true, the Android system never sees the input. For example:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BUTTON_A)
    {
        buttonAPressed = true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I don't know if this is the best way to do it, but that's my work around to it. Hope this helps anyone that needs it!

Comment: It seems to be the approach also recommended by Amazon for Fire TV Remotes and controllers ;-) https://developer.amazon.com/docs/fire-tv/remote-input.html